# Pre-populate the "Post" global action to with text?

Tags: apex, chatter, post

I am trying to pre-populate the Post (FeedItem.TextPost) global action with text. Anyone know a simple way to do this?

Comment: can you provide an example how you want to achieve, through configuration, what is your exact requirement? Little bit description in your question helps us to understand better

Comment: you can refer this, how to post to chatter through process builder https://automationchampion.com/tag/how-to-post-on-chatter-with-process-builder/